# Spyder: plotting results in a web browser

Tags: python, plot, spyder

Is there a way to show the results of a plot in a web browser(ex. chrome) or somewhere else except from the console in Spyder (IDE for python)?

For now I get the plot in the console by using

```
plt.show()
```

and its really difficult to see the results as the plot is really small. Any idea?

Comment: When giving a negative vote please consider to add a comment. You do not help anyone by just giving a negative vote without explanation.

Comment: Consider using Jupyter (formerly known as iPython Notebook), which is browser-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) There is no way to show plots generated in Spyder in a web browser. But you can change your Graphics backend to get bigger plots.

There are two ways of doing that:

1. Running this command in an IPython console before creating a plot:

   `%matplotlib qt`
2. Going to the menu

   `Tools > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics > Graphics Backend`

   and selecting the `Qt` option there.